# Implementation of Neumann-like boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

If we wish to solve an elliptic PDE, say $\nabla^2\phi=\text{given}$, on a domain $\Omega$ with Neumann boundary conditions, $\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot \nabla \phi\Big|_{\partial \Omega}=\text{given}$, being $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ the outward *normal* to the domain,  then Mathematica has a straightforward implementation with `NeumannValue`. For instance, considering two dimensions

```
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - NeumannValue[1, True] ==   0, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, x == 1 && y == 0]}, u, Element[{x, y}, Disk[]]]
```

(Here we have to fix at least one point.) If the condition is now not with the normal but with the *tangent* derivative, as

\begin{align}
\hat{\mathbf{T}}\cdot \nabla \phi\Big|_{\partial \Omega}=\text{given},
\end{align}

being $\hat{\mathbf{T}}=R_{\pi/2}\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ the tangent vector to the domain, is there a direct way to implement the condition with (or without) `NeumannValue` ?

It can be written as the normal derivative of the rotated gradient, but `NeumannValue` only accepts scalars multiplying the gradient, not matrices.

Comment: Review [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html#445164535) section from the documentation: The NeumannValue will replace the integral over n.(c.nabla u ...). Having said that, you *can* use things like `NeumannValue[ f[{-1, 1}*BoundaryUnitNormal[x, y][[{2, 1}]]], pred]` where `f` does something useful with the tangent which is compuated (in 2D) as {-n_y, n_x}. Now, you have some food for thought. Not sure this helps you.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @user21 Not really.